# What is the $n$-th derivative of $\ln(a+x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

> What is the $n$-th derivative of $f(x)=\ln(a+x)$, $a\in\mathbb{R}$

I already computed the first 4 derivatives 
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{1}{a+x}\\
f''(x)&=-\frac{1} {(a+x)^2}\\
f'''(x)&=\frac{2}{(a+x)^3}\\
f''''(x)&=-\frac{6}{(a+x)^4}
\end{align} I'm sure that the $n$-th derivative has to be something with $f^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{1}{(a+x)^n}$, but what about the numerator?

Comment: With the power rule, what are you multiplying into the numerator for each iteration of the derivative?

Comment: It seems that
$$f^{(n)}(x) = \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(a+x)^{n}} $$

Comment: @AndrewChin we always multiply the previous exponent of the previous derivative of $(a+x)$ into the numerator.

Comment: @AndrewChin thank you for the question, it helped me to find the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\frac{(-1)^0}{a+x}\\
f''(x)&=\frac{(-1)^1 \cdot 1} {(a+x)^2}\\
f'''(x)&=\frac{(-1)^2 \cdot 1 \cdot 2}{(a+x)^3}\\
f''''(x)&=\frac{(-1)^3 \cdot 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3}{(a+x)^4}
\end{align}

Can you spot a pattern now?

Comment: Yeah, it's $(n-1)!$ what's missing, right?

Comment: @Doesbaddel: Genau!

Comment: ${}{}{}{}{}{}$:D